# How to set VolumeUp, VolumeDown and mute shortcuts on Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, soundcard

In my config (`~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml`) are my multimedia keys set like:

```
<!-- Keybinding for Volume management -->
<keybind key="XF86AudioRaiseVolume">
  <action name="Execute">
    <command>amixer -q sset Master 3%+ unmute</command>
  </action>
</keybind>
```

With `xev` I checked, those are right keys.

But it does not work. AFAIU, problem is that my soundcard setup has no Master device.

Output of `amixer scontrols`:

```
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',0
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',1
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',2
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',3
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',4
```

I tried like:

```
amixer -q sset IEC958 3%+ unmute
```

but it does not affect volume level.

If I run `alsamixer`, it does not seem look good:

```
┌────────────────────── AlsaMixer v1.1.3 ──────────────────────┐
│ Card: HDA Intel HDMI                 F1:  Help               │
│ Chip: Intel Haswell HDMI             F2:  System information │
│ View: Playback                       F6:  Select sound card  │
│ Item: S/PDIF                         Esc: Exit               │
│                                                              │
│                                                              │
│                                                              │
│                                                              │
│                                                              │
│           ┌──┐     ┌──┐     ┌──┐     ┌──┐     ┌──┐           │
│           │OO│     │OO│     │OO│     │OO│     │OO│           │
│           └──┘     └──┘     └──┘     └──┘     └──┘           │
│        < S/PDIF >S/PDIF 1 S/PDIF 2 S/PDIF 3 S/PDIF 4         │
│                                                              │
│                                                              │
│                                                              │
│                                                              │
│                                                              │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

As you may see, there is also no way no trim volume.

Volume app on start bar works fine, also pavucontrol.

But how to set keyboard shortcuts to work with my setup?

Lubuntu 18.04, Lenovo Thinkpad X240, `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI KT (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I218-LM (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev e4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5227 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 83)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Volume app on start bar works fine, also pavucontrol.

That's the way to go. With the `pactl`-command you can easily control the pulseaudio sound server.

With

```
pactl list sinks
```

you should find the sink  to use, in my system it found only one sink which was listed as `sink #0`.

The command to control the sink volume is

```
pactl set-sink-volume SINK VOLUME [VOLUME ...]
```

Example

```
pactl set-sink-volume 0 -5dB
```

reduces the volume by 5dB. There are more possibilities, you can raise or reduce the volume linear, by percentage etc. Please take a look at `man pactl`.

With

```
pactl set-sink-mute SINK toggle
```

you can toggle between muted and unmuted, replace SINK with your sink number.

Replace the `amixer`-command in your configuration files with the desired `pactl`-command.

One nice effect of using `pactl` is that you will see the changes in your volume bar.

Comment: Great, it works. So, pulse, not alsa. Thank you!